# Stored procedure to update rows in a table that have duplicate value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table `active_user` with 4 columns in a SQL Server database. I want a stored procedure to clean up data.

In the data shown below, I want to update `isActive` to 0 for all unique (`firstName,lastName, isActive`) where `isActive = 1` and `lastModified` < the `lastModified` of (`firstName, lastName, isActive`) grouped orderedBy Desc Top 1.

Sample data before executing the stored procedure:

```
firstName lastName  isActive  lastModified
-----------------------------------------------------
foo         bar        1       2019-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        1       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        1       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        1       2016-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        0       2015-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        0       2014-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo1        bar1       1       2019-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo1        bar1       1       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo1        bar1       0       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo2        bar2       1       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo2        bar2       0       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77
```

Same dataset, after executing the stored procedure:

```
firstName lastName  isActive  lastModified
------------------------------------------------------
foo         bar        1       2019-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        0       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77 //updated
foo         bar        0       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77 //updated
foo         bar        0       2016-11-16 06:43:19.77 //updated
foo         bar        0       2015-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo         bar        0       2014-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo1        bar1       1       2019-11-16 06:43:19.77 
foo1        bar1       0       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77 //updated
foo1        bar1       0       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77 
foo2        bar2       1       2018-11-16 06:43:19.77
foo2        bar2       0       2017-11-16 06:43:19.77
```

In total 4 rows updated.

Here is my attempt in pseudo SQL:

```
update active_user 
set isActive = 0 in (SELECT unique(firstName, lastName, isActive) 
where isActive = 1 
  and lastModified < (select TOP 1 distinct(firstName, lastName, isActive) 
                      where isActive = 1) 
group by (firstName, lastName, isActive) orderBy))
```

I am looking for how to approach this problem so it can be done elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select au.*,
             row_number() over (partition by first_name, last_name, isactive order by last_modified desc) as seqnum
      from active_user au
     )
update toupdate
    set isActive = 0
    where seqnum <> 1 and isActive = 1;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be (partition by first_name, last_name, isActive where isActive=1 order by last_modified desc)

Comment: @eagertoLearn . . . That is not how I interpret the question.  You seem to want all earlier rows to have active set to false.

Comment: yes all earlier rows AND  isActive=1, there might be earlier rows whose isActive=0, those will be untouched. 5th row in the example above

Comment: looks like this is a slow query from PR comment

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number` to identify the row with latest `lastModified` value and set to 1. The rest to 0

```
; with cte as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by firstName, lastName  
                                          order by lastModified desc)
    from   active_user
)
update c
set    isActive = case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end
from   cte c
```

Comment: looks like this is a slow query from PR comment

Comment: @eagertoLearn What do you mean by that ?

Comment: one of the code reviewers commented it will be a slow query when we have few millions rows